# jQuery Mobile 1.4.0: dynamically change header and title of a page

Tags: jquery-mobile

What is the proper way to dynamically change the header (data-role="header") and title () of a jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to add *toolbars* (header / footer) dynamically. Moreover, jQuery Mobile 1.4 offers *internal* and *external* toolbars, it depends whether you want one *toolbar* for all pages, or different one for each page.

If you want an *internal* toolbar, add it to current page (active page), and if you want an *external* one, add it to *pageContainer*. Also, you need to enhance it, either using `.toolbar()` or `.enhanceWithin()`.

After adding *toolbar* dynamically, you **have** to reset current page's height as they add extra padding when added dynamically. `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()` will remove extra padding.

Here is a demo of how to add a *header* to current page.

```
/* get active page */
var page = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

/* add header */
$(".add").on("click", function () {
    $(page).append($("<div/>", {
        "data-role": "header",
            "data-position": "fixed"
    }).append($("<h1/>").text("Header"))).enhanceWithin();

    /* reset height */
    $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
});

/* change title */
$(".change").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui-header .ui-title").text("new title");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hrLc7/)**

---

To add an *external* toolbar.

```
/* get pageContainer */
var pagecontainer = $.mobile.pageContainer;

$(".add").on("click", function () {
    $(pagecontainer).append($("<div/>", {
        "data-role": "header",
            "data-position": "fixed",
            "data-theme": "a"
    }).append($("<h1/>").text("Header"))).enhanceWithin();

    /* reset height */
    $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CVJ78/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Would you be so kind to also explain what to do, if only the title itself (just the content of the h1 tag in the header) needs to be changed? I've tried changing the text of the h1 and this does the job on the header but would not change the content of the title that jqm seems to inject automatically.

Comment: @materialdreams you're welcome. To change the title only, use this `$(".ui-header .ui-title").text("new title");`. It's explained in first block of code and demo.

Comment: Thanks again. May I ask where I might find this kind of information in the jqm documentation?

Comment: @materialdreams [adding headers dynamically](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-dynamic/). Changing header's title, it's not mentioned in docs.